# Tenses in English

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions

> Sandra finds her mobile phone very useful.
>
> 1. She **uses** it all the time
> 2. She **has been using** it all the time.

Which one is correct in the second sentence? Please tell me!

Comment: What would be your own choice, and why?

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case with English tenses, both are completely correct and natural, and might even refer to the same objective circumstances. The difference is **entirely** in how the speaker is choosing to express the temporal relations in what they are saying.

If they say *She uses it all the time*, they are leaving the time unbounded: her use probably includes times from the past into the future (though if she stopped using her phone right now, that would not make the statement false).

If they say *She has been using it all the time* they are reporting on a period from a time in the past up to the present. That doesn't say anything at all about whether she will do so in the future: the speaker is choosing to focus only on the past up to the present.